# Change Xampp Mysql to display errors in Portuguese

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to change mysql to return the error in Portuguese.
I already added in the file my.ini the line "lc-messages = pt_BR"
It still keeps returning the error in English.
Does anyone know how to help me in this?
Before I came to ask for help I already researched and could not solve this

My version of Xampp is v3.2.1

PS: Sorry for the English

Comment: lc_messages, not lc-messages. Also, changing the ini file requires a server restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the language is not so much a XAMPP nor PHP thing but rather involves a MySQL configuration file aka an option file.  Take a look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html). You should change your my.ini file to include this server command option:

```
lc-messages=pt_BR
```

If you are using XAMPP 3.2.1, then you most likely are using MySQL5.6 and the correct way to express this locale change option is to write "lc-messages", i.e. use a hyphen and not an underscore in an option file or on the commandline; see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html).

Be sure to save the file and then you should restart the MySQL server.

Note: the actual environment variable is lc_messages.